# Removing the most frequent character from a string - C++

Tags: string, character

Title says it all - My string will only be formed by digits separated by space e.g. 1 0 3 0 4 0 7 0. What I want to do is remove the most often occurring character and then get 1 3 4 7. There will always be just one digit that is repeated. I tried this but it only removes the duplicates, not the actual occurrence of the character:

```
string newString = "1 0 3 0 4 0 7 0";
sort(newString.begin(), newString.end());
newString.erase(unique(newString.begin(), newString.end()), newString.end());
```

I've also tried to loop over the string character by character and then remove the one that is most occurring but it doesn't work:

```
void countCharacters(const char n[], char count[])
{
 int c = 0; 
 while (n[c] != '\0')
  {
    if (n[c] >= '0' && n[c] <= '9')
        count[n[c] - '0']++;
  }
}

void myFunction()
{
 string newString = "1 0 3 0 4 0 7 0";
 char count[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
 const char *charString = newString.c_str();
 countCharacters(charString, count);
 for (unsigned int z = 0; z < strlen(charString); z++)
        {
            if (count[z] > 1)
                {
                newString.erase(remove(newString.begin(), newString.end(), count[z]), newString.end());
                }
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
void solve() {
 string s = "1 0 3 0 4 0 7 0";
  int mx_count = 0, cnt[10] = {0};
  char mx_occ = '0';
  for(int i = 0; i < int(s.size()); i++) {
    if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9') {
      cnt[s[i] - '0']++;
      if(cnt[s[i] - '0'] > mx_count) 
        mx_count = cnt[s[i] - '0'], mx_occ = s[i];
    }
  }
  queue<int> idxs;
  for(int i = 0; i < int(s.size()); i++) {
    if(!('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9')) continue;
    if(s[i] == mx_occ) idxs.push(i);
    else {
      if(!idxs.empty()) {
        int j = idxs.front();
        idxs.pop();
        swap(s[i], s[j]);
        idxs.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  // instead of the below while loop
  // you can loop on the queue and 
  // erase the chars at the positions in that queue.

  int i = int(s.size()) - 1;
  while(i >= 0 && (!('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9') || s[i] == mx_occ)) {
    --i;
  }
  if(i >= 0) s = s.substr(0, i + 1);
  else s = "";
  cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you declare your string:

```
string newString = "1 0 3 0 4 0 7 0";
```

You can use a replace statement (using a function that will find the most common occurrence for you if you would like to)

```
newString = newString.replace(" 0", " ");
```

If you would like to use a function to tell you which character is the most common, then you will be able to place that into the first argument of the replace function.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! I actually figured it out - I implemented my function to find the character which occurs most often but now I have another problem: I forgot to mention that my line can be like this :